# folder structure and element issue with React

Tags: css, reactjs, directory

I confused about how should folder structure be in React , I just imported individual styles to individual elements but first of all I'm getting `is defined but never used` in console , and second I'm getting 2 buttons although I just added one button and it appears with same style as in `addcontact.css` which I never added to my `ContactList.js` what is actually happening ? is using props returning elements with styles ?!

**Folders structure**

[image: folder structure]

addcontact.css

```css
button{
  display: flex;
  align-self: flex-start;
  width: 5rem;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 2rem;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  border: none;
  background-color: crimson;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 1px black;
}
```

---

ContactList.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import contactlist from './styles/contactlist.css'
const ContactList =  (props) => {
    const renderContactList = props.contacts.map(contact=>{
         return(
             <div className="item">
                 <div className="content">
                     <div>
                     <div className="name">{contact.name}</div>
                     </div>
                     <div>
                     <div className="mail">{contact.email}</div>
                     <button>Delete</button>
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
         );
    });
   return(
         <div className="celled-list">
             {renderContactList}
         </div>
   );
}
export default ContactList;
```

---

AddContact.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import addcontact from './styles/addcontact.css';

class AddContact extends React.Component{
  render(){
      return(
             <main>
                 <h2>Add Contact</h2>
                 <form>
                     <div className="field">
                         <div className="Name-container">
                         <label>Name</label>
                         <input type="text" name= "name" placeholder="Name" />
                         </div>
                         <div className="email-container">
                         <label>Email</label>
                         <input type="Email" name= "Email" placeholder="Email" />
                         </div>
                         <button>Add</button>
                     </div>
                 </form>
             </main>
      );
  }
}
export default AddContact;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use css module syntax with regular css stylesheet.

You are not using the variable created when trying to import the css stylesheet that's why you get the error "is defined but never used".

As in prior comment already stated, just import the whole stylesheet without declaring it as a variable.

Check out the CRA documentation for further info [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-stylesheet).

Answer (score 0):

Try simply importing it without as, like this:

```
import './styles/contactlist.css';
```

Comment: what is the difference ? I'm still getting 2 buttons while I added only one and with same style that I never added